# Am I able to assess any information on a page I pull into an iFrame?

Tags: javascript

This is cross domain..i.e. different domains and I don't have access to the other domain.

Here is the w3 reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

These seem to be things you set, not things you pull.

MDN has this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

Once again things you set.

It sais you can not access most properties from a different domain...if so what are the ones you can access...it does not say all.

If iFrame properties do not provide info. about the content loaded...can I go into the DOM of the window I load into the Iframe( not all properties are inaccessible )?

Comment: It's safe to assume that you are not allowed to read or write

Comment: MDN: Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the same-origin policy, and cannot access most of the properties

Comment: @HiroProtagonist, please take care when selecting tags for your questions.  This is the second time I've had to correct the spelling of [tag:javascript] for you.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its safe to assume anything brought in through an IFrame is not available through your DOM.

With that being said, would it be possible for you to use AJAX to bring in the page content? That would effectively load the content into the page and give you access to the elements in the DOM.

Comment: The documentation states..."SOME of the properties"...I'm going to test this out and post my findings here.